# "Превышать срок"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно сформулировать фразу: "Документ действителен до окончания срока его действия, но не позднее (??) 1 июля 2016 года".
Вот это самое "не позднее" мне и не нравится. А как лучше сказать? "Этот срок не должен превышать..?" или "Не дольше, чем..?"
Что-то мне не нравятся все эти варианты, а как сказать - не знаю.

Comment: Срок действия документа (напр. столько-то месяцев со дня оформления) и указанная дата - независимые ограничения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще в официальной документации так и формулируется "но не позднее", потому как это ёмко и понятно. Вряд ли здесь приветствуется творческий подход. Если речь о "правильной" формулировке, изначальная является наилучшей.

А перефразировать можно сколько угодно, например: "Документ действителен до 1 июля 2016, в случае, если срок его действия не истекает ранее указанной даты". Но это уже получается куда мудрёней изначального выражения.

Answer (score 2):

"Документ действителен до окончания срока его действия (но не позднее  1 июля 2016 года)".

Если нет скобок, то нарушено согласование: действителен не позднее 1 июля 2016 года (неверное сочетание).

Если это оформить как вставную конструкцию, то такое согласование необязательно.

Comment: Если бы в скобках была расшифровка понятия "окончание срока действия", было бы нормально, но там совсем другая дата. Что меняет установка скобок, если всё равно приходится согласовывать там находящееся с чем-то из того, что есть в предложении? Получается либо "документ действителен не позднее", либо "до окончания срока, но не позднее" (две разных даты, из которых первая лишь смутно подразумевается).

Comment: Конструкции в скобках не требуют обязательного ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОГО согласования, их задача - обеспечить понимание смысла. Ваш вариант имеет грамматическое согласование, но он увеличивает объем предложения. Вообще говоря, скобками удобно пользоваться, чтобы упростить текст, избавившись от необходимости согласования.

Answer (score 1):

Нравится Вам это или нет, "но не позднее" самый правильный вариант

Answer (score 1):

Попробую расшифровать для себя смысл фразы "Документ действителен до окончания срока его действия, но не позднее 1 июля 2016 года". Срок - величина, измеряемая в единицах времени (например, два года) и отсчитываемая от отдельно оговариваемой даты. Можно вычислить дату, когда срок заканчивается. Дату окончания можно было бы сопоставить с любой другой на предмет "(не) раньше/позже". Но в рассматриваемой фразе вместо "даты" окончания срока действия фигурирует просто "факт его окончания". Поэтому и повисает в воздухе единственная (и названная) дата: "факт" окончания срока с "датой" грамматически не сопоставить, а если рассматривать остающееся "документ действителен... не позднее 1 июля", тоже получается нечто странное. Исправить фразу, сохранив при этом её канцелярскую изысканность, можно, обозначив словом "дату", "не позднее которой" действителен документ. Попутно можно устранить противоречие между выражениями "до окончания срока его действия" (= весь положенный срок), но "не позднее чего-то" (= но почти с гарантией не весь положенный срок) - заменив "до окончания" на "в пределах", что сразу допускает меньший срок.

Документ действителен **в пределах** срока его действия (указанного там-то), но **до даты** не позднее 1 июля 2016 года.

Comment: Вот, да! Я именно так и рассуждала, поэтому мне это "не позднее" и не нравится. Все-таки канцелярщина и русский язык - это, как говорят в Одессе, две большие разницы)))